# Why does the rank of a covariance matrix effect the degrees of freedom in chi squared distribution?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

In the [wikipedia article on chi squared distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-square_distribution) it states:

> If $Y$ is a $k$-dimensional Gaussian random vector with mean vector $\mu$  and rank $k$ covariance matrix $C$, then $ X = ( Y − \mu )^T C ^{− 1} ( Y − \mu )$  is chi-square distributed with $k$ degrees of freedom.

I know that multiplying by $C^{-1}$ normalises the $Y$. But how does the rank of the covariance matrix effect the degrees of freedom of the sum?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3803529/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2808041/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3442471/321264

Answer (score 0):

If $\ Y\ $ is $k$-dimensional, then $\ C\ $ must be a $\ k\times k\ $ matrix, and therefore non-singular if it has rank $\ k\ $ (as it must do if $\ C^{-1}\ $ is to exist), and positive definite with a unique positive definite square root, $\ H\ $.  Let $\ Z= H^{-1}(Y-\mu)\ $.  Then $\ Z\ $ is $k$-dimensional Gaussian with zero mean and covariance matrix $\ H^{-1}CH^{-1}= H^{-1}H^2H^{-1}=I_{k\times k}\ $,  and $\ X=(Y-\mu)H^{-1}H^{-1}(Y-\mu)=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^kZ_i^2\ $.  Thus, $\ X\ $ is the sum of squares of $\ k\ $ uncorrelated (and hence independent) standard normal variates, and therefore has a chi-squared distribution with $\ k\ $ degrees of freedom.